# Android add drawable image from java code?

Tags: android, drawable

I need to insert in a TextView a drawable that I download from web in the code. So I can't manually put the image in res and in R.drawable.

How can I use it?

Comment: After downloading the bitmap/jpeg from online, you can change to drawable or u can use as it is.

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652798/loading-drawable-from-sd-card answers your question.

Comment: How is a drawable inserted in a TextView?

Comment: Drawable can be inserted as a background in a TextView.

Comment: @VarunKumar yes, you're right

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1) Download image

2) Convert to drawable

3) Set drawable to textView by calling smth like this:

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try {
    /* Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it. */
    URL aURL = new URL("ur Image URL");
    URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
    bis.close();
    is.close();

    Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bm);
    d.setId("1");
    textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,1,0);// wherever u want the image relative to textview
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remote Image Exception", e);
    }
```

Reference url [How to display an image from an URL within textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464506/how-to-display-an-image-from-an-url-within-textview)