# How to make textview with drawable on the left which could be set programmatically from a url coming from server

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

[image: Textview with programmable drawable on the left]

How to make `TextView` with `Drawable` on the left that(drawable) can be set programmaticaly from a url coming from the server.

Comment: You make a network request and update an ImageView. Please share what you have tried to research to implement this feature.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464506/how-to-display-an-image-from-an-url-within-textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first step is to decode the image from the URL.

You could do something like this:

```
String yourUrl = "http://someUrl"; // insert your URL here

// connect, get an instance of the InputStream
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(yourUrl).openConnection();
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

// decode the stream into a Bitmap and create a Drawable from it
Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap);
```

And then, set it as a compound drawable on the left side of your `TextView`:

```
// the order is left, top, right, bottom, so you need to set the first param
yourTextView.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Volley Class to load images 
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html